# Laravel eloquent models with swagger openApi annotations problem

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, swagger, openapi

So in my user model I have a function fullname that returns the full name of the user :

```php
/**
 * @return Attribute
 */
public function fullname(): Attribute
{
    return new Attribute(
        get: fn () => trim($this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname),
    );
}
```

and it works as expected, now i want to add OpenAPI annotations on my model :
I did it like so :

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    ...
       
    protected $appends = [
        'fullname'
    ];

    #[OA\Property(type: "string", example: "Jhon")] 
    private $firstname; 

    #[OA\Property(type: "string", example: "Doe")] 
    private $lastname;
    
    /**
     * @return Attribute
     */
    public function fullname(): Attribute
    {
        return new Attribute(
            get: fn () => trim($this->firstname . ' ' . $this->lastname),
        );
    }
}
```

at this point the function no longer works as intended :

```php
$this->firstname and $this->lastname
```

no longer return values they are null.

Issue : I want to keep the the annotations but also have the function work.

Note : if you access your user through eloquent ex. ( User::all()->first(); ) we get both the first and last name but we don't get the fullname, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/issues/157

according to this issue :
defining the properties on the model will generate a lot of problems with eloquent

I found 3 ways to solve this problem :

**option 1 :** the least amount of refactoring you need to do

keeping the annotations and removing the properties definitions ex :
this :

```php
#[OA\Property(type: "string", example: "Jhon")] 
private $firstname; 

#[OA\Property(type: "string", example: "Doe")] 
private $lastname;
```

will become this :

```php
#[OA\Property(property: "firstname", type: "string", example: "Jhon")] 
#[OA\Property(property: "lastname",type: "string", example: "Doe")]
```

note: the attributes or the annotations must be above a variable or a function or it will generate an error.

**option 2 :** cleaner but adds more work

put your open api declaration somewhere else. ex :

- response resources : https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/issues/157#issuecomment-406204764
- create a new directory (virtual) and put all your OpenAPI annotations there : https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/issues/157#issuecomment-655865772

**option 3 :** and this is what i used

add your propreties to your schema declaration
example :

```php
#[OA\Schema(schema: "IUser", properties: [
    new OA\Property(property: "firstname", type: "string", example: "Jhon"),
    new OA\Property(property: "lastname",type: "string", example: "Doe")
])]
```